# Utils installed using snap unable to write to .bashrc

Tags: permissions, snap, 19.04, bashrc

***Question : Is there any way we can allow snap utilities to write to .bashrc?***

**Below are the steps what I did or tried:**

**I installed vault using *snap* in Ubuntu:19.04**

```
snap install vault
```

*2019-05-26T09:46:49Z INFO Waiting for restart...
vault 1.1.1 from Snapcrafters installed*

**After successful installation I was trying to install vault autocomplete feature using**

```
vault -autocomplete-install
```

**Which is throwing error as below :**

```
root@vault-server:~# vault -autocomplete-install
```

*Error executing CLI: 1 error occurred:*

**open /root/.bashrc: permission denied*

**But if I install vault by downloading binary, add soft-link in /usr/bin, and then try to install autocomplete it gets installed successfully and I can see an new entry in ~/.bashrc**

```
complete -C /opt/softwares/vault vault
```

**FYI :** */opt/softwares is the /path/to/dir where I copied my downloaded binary.*

**Adding info for reference :**
After installing vault using snap :

```
which vault
```

/snap/bin/vault

```
ls -lrt /snap/bin/
```

total 1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 13 May 26 09:47 vault -> /usr/bin/snap

```
ls -lrt /usr/bin/ | grep snap
```

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    ubuntu-core-launcher -> ../lib/snapd/snap-confine

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    snapfuse

lrwxrwxrwx 1 root   root    snapctl -> ../lib/snapd/snapctl

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root   root    snap

```
ls -lrt /usr/bin/ | grep vault
```

Nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to comment.

Maybe, the confinements, specifically `classic` confinement is the thing you need. From https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-confinement

> - Strict
>
>   Used by the majority of snaps. Strictly confined snaps run in complete isolation, and consequently, can not access your files, network, processes or any other system resource without requesting specific access via an interface.
> - Classic
>
>   **Allows access to your system’s resources in much the same way traditional packages do.** To safeguard against abuse, publishing a classic snap requires manual approval, and installation requires the --classic command line argument.
> - Devmode
>
>   A special mode for snap creators and developers. A devmode snap runs as a strictly confined snap with full access to system resources, and produces debug output to identify unspecified interfaces. Installation requires the --devmode command line argument. Devmode snaps cannot be released to the stable channel, do not appear in search results, and do not automatically refresh.

So, you just need to reinstall your `vault` package under classic confinement:

```
sudo snap install vault --classic
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looks like vault currently doesn't support --classic as getting "Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap vault". But still looks like --classic is the only key for my problem till vault team gets snap classic approval I need to live with workaround by manual entry in .bashrc. Thanks.